# Replacement for foobar2000's "Move files" functionality?

Tags: music, music-player

So I'm a recent Ubuntu convert and love it, but theres one thing I need help with: organising my music library.

Previously on Windows I used foobar2000, and had one playlist called "Incoming" where I put all of my new music that hadn't quite made it into my library, and when I decided it was good enough to make it into the collection I could select all the files, right click, "Move files...", and then foobar could move or copy all the files, and accompanying album art into the library folder on my hard drive, into the relevant subfolder for album and artist, and re-name the files nicely.

I realise I could probably duplicate this functionality by writing a shell script but I was wondering what other people do with regards to new music, and organising it? I'd be open to new ways of dealing with new music, perhaps some kind of auto playlist of recently added music, or automatic pruning of new music that I haven't listened to. I'm currently using Banshee to play my music but I'm willing to change if needs be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem as you - match foobar2000 possibilities with something from Linux world.

I tried all I could to no solution. Currently I'm using MPD with Sonata, and new files get to MPD database after I process, tag, move with foobar2000 under Wine.

There is no similar package in Linux. Deadbeef has perhaps 10% of foobar2000 functionality (nice converter included)

For your particular problem (move...), and perhaps something more try Ex Falso. It has option to rename files (move) based on tags

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in some respects Foobar in Wine is the only solution. 
I find it best at converting too, as in many other types of music-file manipulation. For current use: Deadbeef, of course.